# serverless + aws lambda fails at 'Uploading CloudFormation file to S3'

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I have a lambda deployed via `serverless deploy` and it fails at

```
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  Access Denied
```

My company has very tight restrictions around S3. How do I know what S3 bucket is getting access denied so I request access? The `serverless.yml` looks like this:

```
service: some-lambda-name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: 'staging'
  region: us-east-1
  role: arn:aws:iam::12345:role/some-lambda
  memorySize: 512
  deploymentBucket:
    name: lambda-bucket-staging

functions:
  some-lambda-name:
    name: some-lambda-name
    handler: some-lambda-name.lambda_handler
    memorySize: 128
```

edit:

In terraform my deployment role total access to the bucket I expect it to deploy to:

```
{
  "Action": "s3:*",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-bucket-staging",
    "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-bucket-staging/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: IIRC it creates an s3 bucket to keep the templates etc in so you're likely missing the `CreateBucket` permission

Comment: In case of role based authorisation, the principle tag decides who can access the resource. As per AWS documentation If you don't have a principle tag in role than role is user dependent so you must be having the access to assume the role that you are using to upload. Try adding the principle tag with value of the role. Since you already have the complete access in action tag its primarily the user trying to achieve the role is failing. Eventually making the user unauthorised to put object in s3. Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the action-resources set up correctly, and that your aws resource has public access etc.

For example here is are permissions allowing access to **fake** human resources account bucket; notice resources are not all the same!

JSON action-resource example:

[image: img]